# Fixed navbar and right gallery with fixed size items

Tags: html, css, fixed, navbar

This is my first question so, please be gentle.

I am a novice to HTML and CSS and I am trying to achieve something that appears to be outside of my skills.

I have this situation: I need to make a page with left-fixed navigation bar and a right part with a gallery with fixed width items.

I made a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1fbntotr/

```
<div class="left"> <div class="logo"> </div></div> 

<div class="right">

<div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div>
<div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div>
<div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div>
<div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div>
<div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div><div class="item"> </div>


</div>
```

The right part doesn't see the items are ended, so there goes that 'ghost' part in the middle, even though they are using percentages for their width.

I tried anything I found in other discussions but they don't appear to work with my example which has a slightly different layout.

I wonder if there is something basic I'm missing that you might help me with. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: When you say 'ghost' part are you referring to the white space between the purple squares and the black navbar?

Comment: Yes - that part. Didn't know how to explain it better. I could fix the color gap with a uniform white but the logo on the left would anyway not be centered.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to mix fixed elements with percentages and pixels.

Not only do you need the container `.right` to be a percentage but you need the contents to have a percentage width too. Unfortunately you still need to declare the hight in `px`, `em` or `rem`.

You might want to take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) as they handle a lot of issues that can arise from using percentages.

I think this is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/2c2e8j86/

```
.logo {
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#97CC66;
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    margin-top:150px;
}

.left {
    background-color:#000;
    width:19%;
    position:fixed;
    height:1400px;
}

.right { 
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:78.5%;
    margin-left: 19.5%;
}

.item {
    width:25%;
    float:right;
}

.item-inner {
    margin: 0 0 2px 2px;
    background-color:#C7003F;
    height:138px;
}
```

You need to have the gap between the `.item`s on the inside of the container so add an extra `.item-inner` div.

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed what I suspected. I ended up making a layout very similar to this (just the square keep the 1:1 ratio) and I decided to sacrifice the effect that required me to keep the items fixed size, instead. It would have been good to know how to fix it but I could manage with this layout. Thanks for your confirmation that this wasn't viable.

Comment: Not without javascript I don't think